# MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer play skipToNextItem is slow with lag

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using a MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer to play
music, but after skipping songs I notice significant lag.

Here is my "lag" that I have measured, at times it is faster:

- 1.280796
- 1.210124
- 1.019931
- 1.167739

After skipping several songs the delay before you hear sound increases
quite a bit.

---

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] setQueueWithQuery:[MPMediaQuery songsQuery]]; 
    [[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] prepareToPlay];

    NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

    [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(handlePlaybackStateChanged:)
                               name:MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];


    [notificationCenter addObserver:self
                           selector:@selector(handleNowPlayingItemChanged:)
                               name:MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification
                             object:[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer]];

    [[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];

}
```

---

```
-(IBAction)playBtn:(id)sender {                 
    if ([MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer].playbackState !=        MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) {
             [[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] play];
        } else {
            [[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] pause];
        }
}

-(void)skipTrack {

    startTrackChange = [NSDate date];              
    [[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] skipToNextItem];
}


-(void)handleNowPlayingItemChanged:(id)notification {

    NSLog(@"%f",[startTrackChange timeIntervalSinceNow]);
}
```

Comment: More testing.. after skipping several times the music eventually starts to play but it takes a significant amount of time. (10 seconds or more before
you hear any sounds)

Comment: I have created a sample project to reduce the amount of variables,
and still the problem persists: 
-0.092157,-0.268869,-0.237229,-0.074643,-0.096063
,-1.218512,-0.189666,-0.164457
These measurements do not reveal when sound actually starts to become audible, which is way more than the values. Something is very wrong with IOS10.x.

Comment: I tested the IOS Music app on my iPhone6s Plus, by opening up the application, selecting downloaded music, then all songs. Then a song starts to play as expected, then I rapidly tap the next button a couple of times, 
then nothing plays for quite some time. Is this perhaps an IOS bug. I have filed a bug with Apple, but I have no idea how long they will take to respond, if ever.

Comment: Wayne - Is it possible that you are skipping to songs that have not been downloaded from the cloud? After investigating my lag problem, I found that this was the issue for me. Just an idea.

Comment: Yip it was the cloud items causing the delay.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
    MPMediaQuery *mediaQuery = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];

   // filter out cloud items, cloud items cause delays
   [mediaQuery addFilterPredicate:[MPMediaPropertyPredicate
                                predicateWithValue:@NO
                                       forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem]];
```